# Property [products] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Order_Products es una tabla pivote, que la utilizo para la coneccion entre Orders y Products

Desde esta tabla hago la conexión a products para mostrar su Nombre e Imagen entre otras cosas pero al momento de usar soft delete en Productos me dice el error

La idea principal es que, si hago un soft delete de algún producto que está en dicha orden, se pueda continuar viendo en la misma orden, ya que de lo contrario no se podría hacer el correcto seguimiento de dichos productos

**Property [products] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.**

Este es mi modelo Products

```
class Product extends Model{
protected $guarded = [];
use SoftDeletes;
protected $table = "products";

//Relation with web order items 
public function webOrder(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\WebOrder');
}
```

Este es mi modelo de Orders

```
class WebOrder extends Model{
protected $table = "web_orders";
protected $guarded = [];
use SoftDeletes;
{
}
//relation with products to cart
public function order_products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\WebOrderItem');
}

//Relation with WebOrder
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'web_order_products', 'order_id', 'products_id')
        ->using('App\WebOrderProduct')
        ->withPivot(['price', 'id', 'quantity']);
}
```

este es el modelo de mi tabla pivot

```
class WebOrderProduct extends Pivot{

public function product()    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'products_id');
}
```

este es el código del controlador

```
public function show($id){
$orders = WebOrder::with('products')->findOrFail($id)->withTrashed();
//dd($orders);
return view('admin.webOrder.show', compact('orders'));
}
```

este es el código en la vista Show

```
@foreach ($orders->products as $product)
<tr>
    <td><img src="{{Storage::url($product->image) }}"></td>
    <td>{{$product->name }}</td>
    <td>${{number_format($product->pivot->price, 0,",",".")}}</td>
    <td>{{$product->pivot->quantity}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método **`withTrashed()`** nos ayudará a recuperar los modelos eliminados o que tienen en la columna `deleted_at` un valor tipo *datetime*.

Por lo tanto de la forma en que lo deseas usar ahorita no es correcto, por que:

Si encadenas a ese nivel dicho método es como si trataras de recuperar los modelos eliminados de **`WebOrder`** cuando en realidad tu lo que tratas es de recuperar los modelos eliminados de `Product`.

Entonces para tratar de darle solución puedes dentro del método `with()` pasar un vector asociativo y en la query interna ahora si encadenar el método `withTrashed()` para que apunte a la relación `products` y estés en condiciones de recuperar aquellos que han sido eliminados mediante la técnica de *soft deleted*.

Propuesta:

```
WebOrder::with(['products' => function($query) {
            $query->withTrashed();
        }])->findOrFail($id);
```

**Referencias**

- [soft deletes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models)
- [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Nuevamente, muchas gracias <3